# fast lookup for the last element in a Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, optimization, django-queryset

I've a model called Valor. Valor has a Robot. I'm querying like this:

```
Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).reverse()[0]
```

to get the last Valor the the r robot. Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).count() is about 200000 and getting the last items takes about 4 seconds in my PC.

How can I speed it up? I'm querying the wrong way?

Comment: Do you have a very ornate structure of ForeignKey, OneToOneField, or ManyToManyField relationships?

Comment: fwiw, this is slow because you're selecting everything in the `valor` table, instantiating a django model instance for each entry when you convert it to a list (via `.reverse`), and taking only the first item in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your data set is going to be big enough that you may want to denormalize things a little bit.  Have you tried keeping track of the last Valor object in the Robot object?

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    # ...
    last_valor = models.ForeignKey('Valor', null=True, blank=True)
```

And then use a [post_save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#topics-signals) to make the update.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def record_last_valor(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        instance.robot.last_valor = instance

post_save.connect(record_last_valor, sender=Valor)
```

You will pay the cost of an extra db transaction when you create the Valor objects but the last_valor lookup will be blazing fast.  Play with it and see if the tradeoff is worth it for your app.

Comment: This is a good solution to the design problem, but it leaves open the question as to why his design was performing poorly even when given more appropriate queries than his original one. With proper indexing, ordering and limits, his original normalized design should have been 'blazing fast' too. I hope the OP updates the question with his findings.

Comment: Django asked me to change it to:
def record_last_valor(sender, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.robot.last_valor = instance

Comment: I agree Joe, this does not try to answer the underlying DB performance issues.  It seemed like there was already a fair amount of talk about checking indexes and your suggestion about qs.query looked like the best possible way to investigate the checking indexes approach.

Comment: I've tried this approach and I can't get the value saved in the DB.

Comment: Are you sure record_last_valor is being called?  Try adding a `print locals()` or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to record_last_valor.  Or maybe my example code needed an instance.robot.save().

Answer (score 9):

The optimal mysql syntax for this problem would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=y ORDER BY z DESC LIMIT 1
```

The django equivalent of this would be:

```
Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).order_by('-id')[:1][0]
```

Notice how this solution utilizes django's [slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) method to limit the queryset **before** compiling the list of objects.

Answer (score 7):

If none of the earlier suggestions are working, I'd suggest taking Django out of the equation and run this raw sql against your database.  I'm guessing at your table names, so you may have to adjust accordingly:

```
SELECT * FROM valor v WHERE v.robot_id = [robot_id] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is that slow?  If so, make your RDBMS (MySQL?) explain the query plan to you.  This will tell you if it's doing any full table scans, which you obviously don't want with a table that large. You might also edit your question and include the schema for the `valor` table for us to see.

Also, you can see the SQL that Django is generating by doing this (using the query set provided by Peter Rowell):

```
qs = Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).order_by('-id')[0]
print qs.query
```

Make sure that SQL is similar to the 'raw' query I posted above.  You can also make your RDBMS explain that query plan to you.

Comment: qs.query (or .query.as\_sql()) is definitely the way to go for anyone trying to track down this issue from the DB side.  People that are wondering about how slicing / sql limit, order_by(), and filter() are handled at a low level should play with this a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's no order_by clause so I'm wondering about what you mean by 'last'. Assuming you meant 'last added',

```
Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).order_by('-id')[0]
```

might do the job for you.

Comment: In the Valor model I have Meta: ordering = ('id',). Does this make your query the same as mine?

Comment: Do you have an appropriate index on your valor table for robot_id?

Answer (score 3):

django 1.6 introduces .first() and .last():

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#last

So you could simply do:

```
Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).last()
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite fast should also be:

```
qs = Valor.objects.filter(robot=r) # <-- it doesn't hit the database
count = qs.count()                 # <-- first hit the database, compute a count
last_item = qs[ count-1 ]          # <-- second hit the database, get specified rownum
```

So, in practice you execute only 2 SQL queries ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Model_Name.objects.first()
```

//To get the first element

```
Model_name.objects.last()
```

//For get last()

in my case, the last is not work because `there is only one row` in the database
maybe help full for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit clause in django?  This way you can have the db, simply return a single record.

mysql

```
 select * from table where x = y limit 1
```

sql server

```
 select top 1 * from table where x = y
```

oracle

```
 select * from table where x = y and rownum = 1
```

I realize this isn't translated into django, but someone can come back and clean this up.

Comment: limit and reverse, you mean. Right?

Comment: In Django you limit with Python's slicing sintax. Valor.objects.filter(robot=r).reverse()[0:1].get()

Comment: I've just tried that last query and is as slower as my original one.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this, is to use the built-in QuerySet method latest() and feeding it whichever column (field name) it should sort by. The drawback is that it can only sort by a single db column.

The current implementation looks like this and is optimized in the same sense as @Aaron's suggestion.

```
def latest(self, field_name=None):
    """
    Returns the latest object, according to the model's 'get_latest_by'
    option or optional given field_name.
    """
    latest_by = field_name or self.model._meta.get_latest_by
    assert bool(latest_by), "latest() requires either a field_name parameter or 'get_latest_by' in the model"
    assert self.query.can_filter(), \
            "Cannot change a query once a slice has been taken."
    obj = self._clone()
    obj.query.set_limits(high=1)
    obj.query.clear_ordering()
    obj.query.add_ordering('-%s' % latest_by)
    return obj.get()
```